# Why are my grid elements so huge and overlapping with one another?

Tags: html, css, frontend, display, web-frontend

I have a grid on my page, and for some reason no matter what I try, the elements in the grid are massive and overlap with one another, despite a similar grid appearing on a different page of mine that has no issues. It's baffling me why this is happening, as this grid's styling isn't different from my other, working grid.

The HTML:

```
<main class="albumView">
                <ul class="grid">
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src={image1} alt="Hello"></img>
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src={image2} alt="Hello1"></img>
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src={image3} alt="Hello2"></img>
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </main>
```

The CSS:

```
.albumView {
  background-color:rgb(1, 0, 1);
  padding:2rem;
  margin:0;
}

 .albumView > .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(275px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 275px);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(1n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(2n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(3n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li > figure {
  height: 100%;
}

.albumView > .grid > li > figure > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

As you can see here, the images are just giant overlapping blocks:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is overlapping? It could be that the divs are of that height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some changes in your css. You are selecting image with wrong selector and probably images are too large

```
.albumView {
  background-color:rgb(1, 0, 1);
  padding:2rem;
  margin:0;
}

 .albumView > .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(275px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 275px);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(1n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(2n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li:nth-child(3n) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.albumView > .grid > li > figure {
  height: 100%;
}
.albumView > .grid > li > figure > img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
figure{
  margin :0;
}
```

[check codepen](https://codepen.io/sayog/pen/xxRYOvL)